# Android app keeps crashing after adding a specific line of code

Tags: java, android

I am using a navigation bar which is made up of fragments, and whenever I open up the fragment below, the app crashes

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{

    View myView;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(first_layout, container, false);
        addListenerOnButton();
        return myView;
    }


    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radio);
    }

}
```

Now I did some experimenting to find the problem, and it turns out to be this line

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radio);
```

Could anyone explain how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: add the logcat so we can see why the crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 addListenerOnButton(myView);
```

And in addListenerOnButton() method use:

```
public void addListenerOnButton(View v) {
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.radio);
}
```